# Как к ESXi5.5 хосту подключить USB диск в качестве datastore?

Tags: usb, vmware

Как к ESXi5.5 хосту подключить USB диск в качестве datastore?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/worlds-first-esxi-datastore-external-usb-storage-chee-wee-